# Getting error while navigating to next pages and scraping all the data using selenium from the website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hi Here I am trying to scrape all the teacher jobs from https://www.naukri.com/ this url I want all the pages data but I am getting only one page data and getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "naukri.py", line 48, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("arguments.click();", next_page)
  File "/home/nyros/Documents/mypython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/home/nyros/Documents/mypython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/nyros/Documents/mypython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments.click is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.116)
```

The code which I wrote is:

```
import selenium.webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url ='https://www.naukri.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"mypython/bin/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")


driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#qsbClick > span.blueBtn'))).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="skill"]/div[1]/div[2]/input').send_keys("teacher")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="qsbFormBtn"]').click()

data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "srp_container.fl")))
result = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "row")))
for r in result:
    data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "srp_container.fl")))
    result = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "row")))
    for r in result:
        try:
            title=r.find_element_by_class_name("desig").text
            print('title:',title)
            school=r.find_element_by_class_name("org").text
            print('school:',school)
            location=r.find_element_by_class_name("loc").text
            print("location:",location)
            salary=r.find_element_by_class_name("salary").text
            print("salary:",salary)
        except:
            pass
            print('-------')
    next_page = r.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[59]/a/button")
    driver.execute_script("arguments.click();", next_page)
```

Please help me anyone Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of `driver.execute_script("arguments.click();", next_page)`, have you tried `next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[59]/a/button")` and `next_page.click()`?

Comment: Then getting like this selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[59]/a/button"}
@shanylong

Comment: That probably means that the xpath of the element updates everytime a nextpage is triggered. Check the xpath of the nextpage button on the second page and see whether it matches that of the xpath you used in your code. If it does not match, then you will have to implement something which modifies the xpath accordingly so that selenium is able to locate the right element.

Comment: Yes it is changed then which path should I need to keep @shanylong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the element index of the 'next' button changes from 59 in the first page to 60 in the next pages, you can just find all elements on the page which have class `"grayBtn"`, and click on index [-1] of the list returned, as this will always provide the next button. I removed some unnecessary parts of your code too, like repeated importations as well as unnecessary button clicks. I instantly directed to the page containing the list of results for teachers, instead of entering "teacher" into the search field on the home page. I was left with the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re    

Category = input("Category?")
Category = re.sub(" ", "%20", Category)
Type = re.sub(" ", "-", Category.lower())

url ='https://www.naukri.com/' + Type + '-jobs?k=' + Category
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"mypython/bin/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)

data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "srp_container.fl")))
result = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "row")))
for res in result:
    data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "srp_container.fl")))
    jobs = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "row")))
    for job in jobs:
        try:
            title=job.find_element_by_class_name("desig").text
            print('title:',title)
            school=job.find_element_by_class_name("org").text
            print('school:',school)
            location=job.find_element_by_class_name("loc").text
            print("location:",location)
            salary=job.find_element_by_class_name("salary").text
            print("salary:",salary)
        except:
            pass
            print('-------')
    Button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grayBtn")[-1]
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight - 1300)")
    Button.click()
```

As requested, here is the modified code to append data to a pandas dataframe and convert the dataframe to excel:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Title', 'School', 'Location', 'Salary'])

Category = input("Category?")
Category = re.sub(" ", "%20", Category)
Type = re.sub(" ", "-", Category.lower())

url ='https://www.naukri.com/' + Type + '-jobs?k=' + Category
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"mypython/bin/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)

data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "srp_container.fl")))
result = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "row")))
i = 0
for res in result:
    data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "srp_container.fl")))
    jobs = WebDriverWait(data, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "row")))
    for job in jobs:
        try:
            title=job.find_element_by_class_name("desig").text
            print('title:',title)
            school=job.find_element_by_class_name("org").text
            print('school:',school)
            location=job.find_element_by_class_name("loc").text
            print("location:",location)
            salary=job.find_element_by_class_name("salary").text
            print("salary:",salary)
            df.loc[i] = [title, school, location, salary]
            i += 1
        except:
            pass
            print('-------')
    Button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("grayBtn")[-1]
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight - 1300)")
    Button.click()
df.to_excel("all_results.xlsx")
```

Comment: @shanylog why that while loop and what is that str(x) could you explain it if you dont mind

Comment: Sorry, just edited to simplify my code a little. Hope this helped!

Comment: getting error like this
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="grayBtn">...</button> is not clickable at point (240, 570). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ppContainer">...</div>

Comment: You will also need to add code to scroll to the bottom of the page then, I will add that into my code to show you.

Comment: I added all the code in the question which I wrote  @shanylong

Comment: No it not worked 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[60]/a/button"}

Comment: @stack Please try again, I just updated my answer. Also, you will need to fix the issue where the search field has a randomly misplaced comma.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209131/discussion-between-stack-and-shanylong).